# Объясните, по какому правилу стоит запятая

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

> *Москва, Российская Федерация*

Конечно, здесь без запятой никто не напишет, но по какому правилу она стоит? Не уточнение же, ведь  *Российская Федерация* более широкое понятие чем *Москва*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это тот случай, когда перечисляются пункты в адресе: *страна, город, улица, дом, корпус, квартира.* Или наоборот в англоязычных странах. Так же могут перечисляться, например, паспортные данные.

В другом контексте может фигурировать ***Москва Российской Федерации.*** Уточнение может быть потому, что это официальный документ, для полного исключения двусмысленности или в том случае, если и правда могла бы идти речь об одной из американских Москв. Но строго они произносятся на английский лад.